# Disable or hide fields that are not applicable

Tags: html, user-interface

These are more of user interface design questions

1. Sometimes fields on an HTML form may not be applicable for a particular criteria (say based on the selection of an item from a pulldown menu). In such a situation, is it better to hide the field or to simple disable/gray it out? One thing I see in that is: HTML hiding fields may affect the layout of the page or have extra white space (if visibility is set to hidden)
2. When a form is being submitted, is it better (in general) to present a confirmation page before the user commits the information?  Is there a a standard for design of this?

Comment: Probably a question better suited to: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Will try posting there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I believe it's better to hide the element, to remove possible confusion and to make the page cleaner. If you use `display: none`, instead of `visibility: hidden`, it will remove the extra whitespace.
2. I don't think it's necessary to have a confirmation page, unless there's payment involved.